# How to power down bluetooth on startup, but leave it accessible

Tags: pi-3, boot, bluetooth, raspbian-jessie, pixel

The majority of the time, I won't want to use the bluetooth on my pi, I've found how to do it with either the GUI or using bluetoothctrl at the command line, but I really don't see a way to do it automatically at boot. There's lots of stuff on disabling bluetooth entirely, but I wan to be able to easily turn it on if I want to.

Then again, I'm pretty new to both the pi and linux, so maybe there's a script I could write to do it with bluetoothctrl?

Sorry for the rambling, I'm just trying to be as complete as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the startup service:

```
# sudo systemctl disable bluetooth
```